# Bouncycastle: X509CertificateHolder to X509Certificate?

Tags: certificate, deprecated, bouncycastle, x509

In versions prior to r146 it was possible to create `X509Certificate` objects directly.
Now that API is deprecated and the new one only deliveres a `X509CertificateHolder` object.

I cannot find a way to transform a `X509CertificateHolder` to `X509Certificate`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you have a link to the online API documentation?

Comment: @SteffenHeil,  You should put the answer in the answer section so we can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I will answer to my own questions, but not delete it, in case someone else got the same problems:

```
return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(certificateHolder);
```

And for attribute certificates:

```
return new X509V2AttributeCertificate(attributeCertificateHolder.getEncoded());
```

Not nice, as it is encoding and decoding, but it works.

Comment: X509V2AttributeCertificate is now deprecated. I'm not sure what to use or how to parse. X509AttrCertParser is not deprecated, but engineRead() returns an X509V2AttributeCertificate which is deprecated.

Comment: I like this becausue it uses pure java methods. Steffen Heil's solution uses BC again and the class names are looking so that it could be changed in future.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is this one :)

```
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateHolder.getEncoded());
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
```

Comment: Too verbose, @SteffenHeil answer seems to be the most "standard" method.

Answer (score -2):

This is an possibility to get the `X509CertificateHolder` to `X509Certificate` and `toString`. (first sentence of the code is irrelevant)

```
X509CertificateHolder selfSignedCertificate = CertificateUtils.selfSignCertificate(certificationRequest, keyPair.getPrivate());
byte[] content = selfSignedCertificate.getEncoded();
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
logger.debug("cert: {}", cert.toString());
```

........

Comment: You should add some explanation.