# BouncyCastle AttributeCertificate to file and vice versa

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Does anybody know how to write an attribute certificate to a file. As well as to read the byte[] and turn that into an attribute certificate?

Comment: you may want to look into [X509AttributeCertificateHolder](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509AttributeCertificateHolder.html)

Comment: Thanks, was able to solve the problem.

Comment: feel free to answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the encoding of the certificate:

```
X509V2AttributeCertificate certitificate = new X509V2AttributeCertificate(attributeCertificateHolder.getEncoded());

// Store to file
String fileName = "test.txt";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
fos.write(certitificate.getEncoded());
fos.close();

// Read from file
byte[] readCertificate = Files.readAllBytes(new File(fileName).toPath());
X509V2AttributeCertificate decodedCertificate = new X509V2AttributeCertificate(readCertificate);
```

There exists another option to read the byte array and decode it to a certificate:

```
X509AttrCertParser parser = new X509AttrCertParser();
parser.engineInit(new FileInputStream(fileName));
X509AttributeCertificate certificate = (X509AttributeCertificate) parser.engineRead();
```

After all there is a problem with the `X509AttributeCertificate` because it is deprecated. I have not found any solution for it up to now. Hints for this solution are taken from [Bouncycastle: X509CertificateHolder to X509Certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370368/bouncycastle-x509certificateholder-to-x509certificate/8960906#8960906).

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating the attribute certificate yourself using bouncy-castle, you are most probably using [X509AttributeCertificateHolder](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509AttributeCertificateHolder.html). In that case you can write the attribute certificate in PEM format using [JcaPEMWriter](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMWriter.html).

```
// create the attrCertHolder
X509AttributeCertificateHolder attrCertHolder = ...

// write as pem format
JcaPEMWriter pemWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(new FileWriter("<directory-path>/attribute_cert.pem"));
pemWriter.writeObject(attrCertHolder);
pemWriter.flush();
```

To retrive the certificate from file, use [PEMParser](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMParser.html):

```
PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader("<directory-path>/attribute_cert.pem"));
X509AttributeCertificateHolder attrCertHolderRetrived = (X509AttributeCertificateHolder) pemParser.readObject();
```

Compare they are equal:

```
// Compare the encoded byte arrays and not with equals() method
boolean equals = Arrays.equals(attrCertHolder.getEncoded(), attrCertHolderRetrived.getEncoded());
Preconditions.checkArgument(equals, "original and retrived attribute certs do not match");
```